# Bluemix REST Push notifications

Tags: rest, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to send a push notification using the REST client in (https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfrestapi/imfswagger/docs?code=NyJX9A#!/push/sendMessage_post_31)

Is there an error with the authorization field? It will not let me add anything to it and I can't  try out my call without it. Any ideas?

[image: Authorization field is required but not letting me add anything to it. Have tried in Safari and Chome both unsuccessful.]

Comment: To understand you correctly, are you saying the authorization field in the UI is not editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This swagger doc was designed to automatically grab the authorization header from the AMA service. When you insert your valid appId, swagger then sends a REST request to get the OAUTH authorization header from your app on Bluemix. That field is then auto filled with the response.

If you are not getting the header in a reasonable amount of time you may need to reload the page and try again. I have had some issues in the past but have gotten it to work. I will probably open a defect against the dev team on this if the problem continues.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: There seems to be two sets of documentation for Push notifications one has an Authorization field the other had App secret. Is one for Bluemix service Push and the other for Bluemix  service iOS 8 Push?

Comment: yes they are separate sets of services. We are working to consolidate them to avoid confusion in the future.